# How to record a Qt5 application window with minimal to zero CPU overhead on Windows or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, gpu, qt, screen-recorder

I'm writing a real-time volume rendering application that runs purely on the CPU. It's quite fast but nevertheless the more CPU power the better for interactivity - basically, I'm designing it to use CPU resources to the maximum. I need to record a demo of the application. Now in the past I've used OBS studio on Linux to record a walkthrough for an RTS game, and I recall that there definitely was some CPU overhead. This is unacceptable for my volume renderer demo.

That said, the question is:

Given a desktop machine with an NVIDIA GTX 1060 6 Gb GPU, is it possible to record a purely Qt5 application that does not output into directx or opengl using the said GPU as the encoder with 0 CPU overhead? Do I need to modify the source maybe to leverage some library that would allow me to copy the framebuffer and encode on the fly using the GPU only?

Edit:

To make it more clear. Primarily, I'm interested in an application that I can launch an record the window of my program, not in a library that I can use my own project as a programmer (i.e. via its API). But, if there is a way  to solve the problem in the latter way, that will be fine too.

Comment: I believe this should be on stackoverflow as it's essentially a programming question.

Comment: @djsmiley2k primarily I'm interested in standalone recording applications that avoid CPU overhead, such as those based on NVIDIA ShadowPlay.

Comment: Ok I've retracted my flag after the edits.

Comment: @djsmiley2k TY for the proofread!

Comment: Unless the whole recording fits into memory, I don't see how you can completely avoid the CPU overhead necessary to access the file system. There are accelerated blits from frame buffer memory into main memory that don't use CPU (though they use the bus), but the CPU will need to do the saving. And I don't know any ready-made application that does this.

Comment: @dirkt what about the "shadowplay" from NVIDIA that is meant to remove CPU overhead?

Comment: I don't doubt Shadowplay removes *some* CPU overhead, but I'd be really surprised if it bypasses the OS and suddenly starts to access disks from the GPU. I'll believe that when I see that (you're welcome to demonstrate it to me), because there are so many problems with this (coherency), and I'd also immediately remove any NVidida cards I find from my machines -- that's a HUGE security hole.

Comment: Video capture cards - same thing (PCI-E to disk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the only zero-overhead solution seems to be to use the HDMI output to connect to an external recording device, such as a laptop or a dedicated video capture box, and then use the "duplicate screen" mode.